# how to write a function for numbers

Tags: c++, function, integer

Write a function that reads positive numbers from the user, and returns the largest number and outputs it.  The function signature should be int largest();
So my question is, I'm not sure how to write function. Would I do something like an into main(); or is it something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next," or "which technology to use" are discussion-oriented questions which involve answers that are either based on opinion, or which are all equally valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already given the function signature: `int largest()`, so that's exactly how you'd write the function (exactly like `int main();`):

```
// Declares the function
int largest();
// Defines the function:
int largest()
{
    // The function MUST return an int (or something convertible) otherwise it will not compile
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can combine the declaration with the definition:

```
int largest()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tas, I figured it was like that but I wasn't to sure!